# Dirac's Prediction of Antiparticles

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter

So I was watching a video and it was talking about the equation
$$
E^2=p^2c^2+m^2c^4,
$$
and they pointed out the square root to find $E$ could yield negative energies, which Dirac interpreted as the existence of antiparticles. I know Dirac's equation he developed implied the existence of a positron, but what does the negative energy actually mean/signify and how does it link to antiparticles as particles and antiparticles both have the same rest mass, and here the same rest energy.

Comment: Historically speaking it was more that the Klein-Gordon equation had negative-energy solutions corresponding to an electron-like particle with charge $+e$ and Dirac's gamma-matrices were meant to avoid this by putting the two charges $\pm e$ and two spins $\pm \hbar/2$ into a 4-dimensional vector wavefunction, so that he could say "and we don't need to worry about those $+e$ solutions for now because an electron can't dynamically evolve into one," which wasn't at all clear for the Klein-Gordon equation.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of antiparticles being connected with negative energy is related to the notion of the [Dirac sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_sea). Bot essentially arise from misinterpreting the Dirac equation as an equation for a *wavefunction* (i.e. as a direct analogue of the Schrödinger equation) instead of interpreting it as an equation for a *quantum field*.

If you make a plane wave ansatz $\psi(x) = u(\vec p)\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}px}$ with $p$ a four-momentum $p = (E_p,\vec p)$, then you find that solutions for $E_p$ positive and negative are possible, in the cases where $u(\vec p)$ fulfills
$$ (p\cdot \gamma - m) u(\vec p) = 0$$
or
$$ (p \cdot \gamma + m) u(\vec p) = 0,$$
respectively. (The $\gamma$ are the [gamma matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices).) Now, if you believe that $\psi(x)$ is a "wavefunction" and $p$ denotes the momentum of the particle this wavefunction belongs to, then you are obviously led to the belief that the Dirac equation predicts the existence of particles with negative energy. The initial idea of the Dirac sea was that all these negative energy states below the "vacuum" of zero energy are *filled* - and infinite sea of particles, and that a "hole" in these states - simply an unoccupied state - was an antiparticle.

In modern quantum field theory, this interpretation is all but obsolete. The Dirac equation is *not* a quantum equation for the wavefunction of a fermion, but the *classical equation of motion* for a fermionic field. The solutions of positive and negative energy (now called "frequency" rather than energy since they do not correspond to the actual energy of a particle anymore) are closely related to the creation and annihilation operators of the fermion and anti-fermion associated with the quantum field $\psi$, so the negative frequency solution still carries significance as predicting anti-particles, but no longer requires an infinite sea of negative-energy states to be filled in order for the vacuum to be stable.